# Can someone add some "Informatica" tags to Database Administrators for their tools?

Tags: support

Can someone with privileges please add some Stack Exchange tags for Informatica products to dba.stackexchange.com?  They have several products, so if you'd like each one and a description for each, let me know.

**For starters:**

Informatica-PowerCenter-Designer

Informatica-MetaData-Manager

Comment: Have you got a particular QUESTION that needs the tag?